What variables are permissible in OBS's "Filename Formatting" field?
I want the default filename to be ISO 8601-1:2019+A1:2022-compliant (because adhering to the ideal, RFC 9557, is infeasible). However, I've been unable to ascertain whether a variable exists for a numeric timezone. Usually, this is %Z, but this outputs GMT for me, instead of the desired +0000 (expanded, +00:00) as would be specification-compliant. The best that I've achieved in this case is +%CCYY%MM%DDT%hh%mm%ss%Z.
For this use case and others, I want to more broadly know how to ascertain which values are permissible (and, ideally, what values they are able to output). I expect documentation to exist, but I've been unable to locate any.

Per a helpful answer from reddit (paraphrased):

If you mouse over the filename box, a list of variables should pop up (does on Windows, version 24.0.3).

...I've been able to acquire a list of valid variables, which I've formatted nicely (as an HTML table) at gitlab.com/-/snippets/4772474.
However, SE doesn't permit ths in a tbody, so I've provided them undermentioned as YAML:
#!/usr/bin/env -S xdg-open
"%CCYY": Year, four digits
"%YY": Year, last two digits (00-99)
"%MM": Month as a decimal number (01-12)
"%DD": Day of the month, zero-padded (01-31)
"%hh": Hour in 24h format (00-23)
"%mm": Minute (00-59)
"%ss": Second (00-59)
"%%": A % sign
"%a": Abbreviated weekday name
"%A": Full weekday name
"%b": Abbreviated month name
"%B": Full month name
"%d": Day of the month, zero-padded (01-31)
"%H": Hour in 24h format (00-23)
"%I": Hour in 12h format (01-12)
"%M": Minute (00-59)
"%p": AM or PM designation
"%s": Time in seconds since UNIX epoch
"%S": Second (00-59)
"%Y": Year, last two digits (00-99)
"%y": Year
"%z": ISO 8601 offset from UTC in timezone
"%Z": Timezone name or abbreviation
"%FPS": Frames per second
"%CRES": Base (canvas) resolution
"%ORES": Output (scaled) resolution
"%VF": Video format

Ultimately, %z provides what I desire.
